# Spark, use local hard disk instead of hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I've managed to run hadoop and spark as explained in https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/hadoop/install-configure-run-spark-on-top-of-hadoop-yarn-cluster/

However, as a beginner, I find running short examples on local machines are way easier.

For example, for a code `airportsNameAndCityNames.saveAsTextFile("out/airports_by_latitude.text")`

It is easier to look at `/home/foo/out/airports_by_latitude.text` than `hdfs://node-master:9000/user/hadoop/out/airports_by_latitude.text` which I don't currently know how to look at with my editor.

So my question is, is there a way to use local storage (not hadoop) when running spark

I found if I comment out `HADOOP_HOME` below (effectively nulling HADOOP_CONF_DIR), it seems to run on local storage (not hadoop), but wonder if there's more elegant way .

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH

export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```

Comment: remember that every executor will write a piece of that txt to their own local file systems...may work on standalone, but will be a headache clustered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple way is to explicitly specify the file system you want to read in :

```
sc.textFile("file:///home/foo/out/airports_by_latitude.text")
```